# Jenkins, Xcode 8.2.1 can not find the provisioning profile though it exists

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am running an iOS build on Jenkins locally. Using Xcode 8.2.1. Using manual signing (i.e. provisioning profile, Team and Signing Certificate correctly selected in Target-> General section.). When I build the app through Xcode, the app builds and archives fine using my ad-hoc distribution certificates. However, when I try building using Jenkins, I get the following error (I am using my own build script to build the app and not using the Jenkins Xcode build plugin)-

```
Check dependencies
[BCEROR]No profile matching 'xxx' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'xxx'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
```

Btw, I already tried the following but those did not help-
copying the provisioning profile in question to the `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` location.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue while building using Jenkins ....did you got any solution

Comment: Any solution ? Same issue for me.

Comment: ** You can try this solution** https://stackoverflow.com/a/54851051/6183248