# jenkins provisioning profile issue

Tags: xcode, jenkins, provisioning-profile

Check dependencies
No iOS profile matching 'Nitin xxxxxxx/xyzCAppStore' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'Nitin xxxxxxx/xyzCAppStore'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

have tried below things

http://code-dojo.blogspot.in/2012/09/fix-ios-code-signing-issue-when-using.html

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin

Comment: And you are sure you added the code signing cert and private key to the keychain for the account that is running Jenkins?  Can you show the cert in the keychain, selected so we can see that it is valid and has the matching private key?

Comment: @wottle : Yes its has private key, have checked multiple times and able to build and archive  successfully with Xcode

Comment: Is Jenkins running under the same user account?  Did you copy the profile to the Jenkins directory?  Also, what are your Xcode build settings?

Comment: @wottle : Yes running under same user account and i have copied provisioning under Jenkins Directory ~/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles, what i dont understand is its failing in archive only.

Comment: @wottle : would be great if you can give me your availability timing

Comment: @wottle I am also facing same issue but in my case Jenkins is running on AWS Ubuntu instance and mac laptop is a slave node .......details are here.....i am badly stuck please help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580092/jenkins-build-failed-xcode-couldnt-find-a-provisioning-profile-matching

Answer (score 2):

**I have solved same problem by following steps**

- Switch to your Jenkin Account [Login to your Jenkins Account]
- Install all required certificates and provisioning in keychain in Jenkin-Account
- Jenkins/Home/workspace or may be different on your Mac [you need to locate the workspace] go to this location.
- You will find the Xcode project which is created by Jenkin local server-- Open this Xcode project -- set provisioning and certificates
- close the project
- open localhost:8080 build your project from Jenkin

**jenkins provisioning profile issue will be solved**