# Jenkins Build Failed : Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, jenkins, code-signing-certificate

I have Jenkins Master running on Aws instance of Ubuntu and created mac laptop as slave , when I ran using Xcode in mac loptop build is successful but when I trigger it from Jenkins it's giving.

```
     error : 

        Check dependencies : No profiles for 'com.xyz.abc' were found: Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.xyz.abc'. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2' 

* ARCHIVE FAILED * The following build commands failed: Check dependencies (1 failure) Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure.
```

Ps :

I have already tried to read previous post but most of them were having Jenkins running on MAC, also xcode is running on same server which is not my case.

As I am able to run my project in xcode I feel that my code signing & provisioning profile are correct. Furthermore now I am able to create IPA using 
Xcode option :

**Product --> Archive in Xcode in Mac Laptop**

Then why jenkins is not able to create ipa ?

I also have moved all keys in login.keychain to system.keychain

I have connected jenkins master(ubuntu) to slave(mac) using java slave-agent.jnlp

Jenkins Console Output :

===========================================================
== Available provisioning profiles
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v

27) XXXXX "Mac Developer: Ashish Karpe (YYYYY)"

Which is similar as in xcode in mac laptop so I am not able to figure out what is wrong her !

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: bty when I deleted all xyz.mobileprovison from /Users/Shared/Jenkins/MobileDevice/ProvisioningProfile still Jenkins console output is showing : Available provisioning profiles
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v  14 valid identities found
== Can we find the requested provisioning profile ?

Comment: So I have doubt , where Jenkins is looking for provisioning profiles ?

Comment: any jenkins and ios build master here to help me out !

Comment: Are you using a jenkins ios plugin?

Comment: @wottle yes I am using xcode jenkins plugin

Comment: @wottle any Idea ?

Comment: No.  I haven't used the xcode jenkins plugin,  we just used shell scripts to run our builds from Kenkins, which meant it would use the logged in user's keychain for the signing identiy.  Does the xcode plugin allow you to specify / provide the certi and private key for signing?  Maybe it's not using the keychain, but its own secure storage for that? Have you set it up as indicated in these instructions: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin#XcodePlugin-Signing

Comment: @wottle I refereed https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin#XcodePlugin-Signing .... did "Import developer profile" on jenkins side still getting same error ! bty if I do this and then do I have to update jenkins side every time if certificates for provisioning profiles are change or this will keep imorting new profiles from Xcode ?

Comment: You would need to do it every time you change a cert or provisioning profile.  The developer profile is just an archive that contains a snapshot of the certificate, its private key, and the provisioning profile at a point in time.

Comment: I feel that my  Development Team ID was wrong I tried with new Id, got this error : Code Signing Error: "PatientPortal" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor.

Comment: Edited : Furthermore now I am able to create IPA using Xcode option :

Product --> Archive in Xcode in Mac Laptop

Comment: @wottle "You would need to do it every time you change a cert or provisioning profile" ..... if this is to be done every time in jenkins then how to automate this ? ie we I add new device to my distribution profile then my provisioning profiles gets updated then do I need to export it from xcode and import it in jenkins then how my CI / CD will working ?

Comment: I would consider something like the fastlane tools to automatically get the latest profile. We don't, for internal reasons - we have the provisioning profile in our version control system and check it out and explicitly use it in our build script.  I'm not sure how to automate the import into Jenkins because we don't use the plugin to do builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last I got the solution and now I can saw we can build IPA from Jenkins Master (Ubuntu AWS instance) using MAC laptop as slave.

My mistake was there were too many provisioning profiles created. I Xcode on Mac laptop when I used one profile (10 digit Development Team ID) which was working properly so I used same on Jenkins side but it failed !

Furthermore Jenkins showed all the detected profiles when I configured Provisioning profiles on Jenkins master and tried with another 10 digit  Development Team ID which worked for me.

All together now I am able to create IPA using Jenkins build but I am not sure why my profile which worked in Xcode worked but didn't worked in Jenkins.

Since, my task is done to marking it here as Answer so in case someone else face similar issues, he can try with 10 digit Development Team ID to get it working !

Hope so this helps someone as I was frustrated a lot and had started hating IOS Deployment !